Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue mesure in in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Prove or give a counterexample.
Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue mesure in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Prove or give a counterexample.

If $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, such that $\lambda(A)>0$, then there exist $x,y \in A$ with $|x-y|$ a irrational number.

Solution:
If $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, with $\lambda(A)>0$, then consider $D:=\{|x-y|:x,y\in A\}$, if I can prove that $\lambda(D)>0$ then $D$ can not be countable, so at leats there is some irrational numer in $D$ and we are done. But is this the way to do it?

Let $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and consider the closure of $\overline{A}$ with the usual topology. If $\lambda(A)=0$ then $\lambda(\overline{A})=0$.

Solution: False, $A=\mathbb{Q}$, then $\lambda(\mathbb{Q})=0$, but $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$, and $\lambda(\mathbb{R})=\infty.$

If $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, with $\lambda(\overline{A})=0$ then $\lambda(A)=0$

Solition:
By definition of closure, we have that $A \subseteq \overline{A}$, so $0\leq \lambda(A) \leq \lambda(\overline{A})=0$, then $\lambda(A)=0$.

Let $A\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, with $int(A),\overline{A} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, then $A \in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Solution:
There is a hint to use some modified version of Vitali's Set. First I think have some problems with something from the basis, for example, $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the smallest $\sigma$- algebra that contain all the open sets for the usual topology. So in particular, for any kind of set $E \in \mathcal{P(\mathbb{R})}$, $int(E),\overline{E} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ as by definition are open and closed sets that satisfies some property.
So for the statement, The Vitale set is a counter example, because it's not borel(?).

Let $A \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, such that $int(A), \overline{A} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, and $\lambda(int(A))=\lambda(\overline{A})\in$, then $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Solution:
I tried to use the fact that $int(A)\subseteq A \subseteq \overline{A}$, and by monotony of the mesure but we get that $\lambda(int(A))=\lambda(A)=\lambda(\overline{A})$, but that do not mean that $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
So I'm trying to make a counter example, take the Vitali set $V$ on $[0,1]$, and define $A_n:=V \cap [0,\frac{1}{n}]$, $n\geq 1$.
Consider $$V_\infty:=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$$
As $V_\infty \subseteq V$, then $V_\infty$ does not contain intervals so $int(V_\infty)=\emptyset$, and $\lambda(int(V_\infty))=0$.
Further more every $A_n$ is dense in $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$, therefore
$$\overline{V_\infty}=\overline{\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n} \subseteq \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\overline{A_n}= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]=\{0\}$$
Then $\lambda(int(V_\infty))=\lambda(\overline{V_\infty})=0$, but $V_\infty$ is not borel.
Some suggestions for improvement?

For 1, you can slightly reframe it as follows: Let $D$ be such that it does not contain any irrational. Then, $D \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \implies \lambda(D) \leq \lambda(\mathbb{Q}) = 0$, which is a contradiction.

Also, these are too many questions in a single post. Please point out the specific concern you have in your solution.

For 5., compute $\lambda ( \overline{A} \setminus A^\circ )$ and note that $\lambda$ is a complete measure.

${\cal B}(\mathbb R)$ usually refers to the Borel sigma algebra. We continue under this assumption (though the answers remain the same even if you consider the strictly larger Lebesgue sigma algebra).

Argue by contradiction, assuming for all $x,y\in A$, $x-y \in \mathbb Q$. Let $x \in A$, then $A \subseteq x+ \mathbb Q$ and therefore $\lambda (A) \le \lambda (\mathbb Q)=0$.

Perfect.

Perfect.

False. The interior and closure of any set are Borel sets (and therefore Lebesgue) as they are open and closed respectively. But there are sets which are not Lebesgue measurable (e.g. Vitali) and therefore not Borel.

False. Let $V\subseteq [0,1]$ be a set which is not Lebesgue measurable and consider $A=V \cup [2,\infty)$.  Both interior and closure of $A$ have infinite measure.  The set itself is clearly not Lebesgue (or Borel) measurable, because its intersection with $[0,1]$ is $V$.


